# HTML posting removes line breaks

Tags: html, textarea

I have a really simple html / php code. It has only a textarea and a send button.

In the textarea, i have a text what has 3 new lines at the begining of the text. I need those line breaks.

After, when i submitting the form, for some reason, it is chop 1 of the line break at the begining of the text. And when i send it again, it do it again, remove line breaks, while the begining of the content is not a text.

Why is it happening?
I tried it with FF, Chrome, Safari, Oprea, IE with the same result.

You can test it with this code:

```
<?php
if (empty($_POST["operation"])) {
    //Init the textarea value if form not submitted
    $_POST["message"] = "\r\n\r\n\r\nThis is\r\na multiline text";
}
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Multiline test</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
</head>
<body>
    <form method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]; ?>">
    <textarea style="width: 200px; height: 150px;" name="message"><?php echo $_POST["message"]; ?></textarea>
    <input type="submit" value="send" />
    <input type="hidden" name="operation" value="send" />
    </form>
</body>
```

Comment: You should if possible think about using CSS to position the message. It would probably be easier too.

Comment: It does not happen when the first char before the newlines is f.e. a space. I have no idea why this happens, and can't find any info in HTML specs after a quick look. You can prevent this by writing your PHP echo statement that populates the textarea onto the beginning of the next line.

Comment: css is not an option. this is a module, when you want to reply to a message. I want to add 3 new lines to separate the quoted message.

Comment: if nothing helps, i will add an extra space, but it is unbelivible for me. i posted 3 line breaks, i want get back 3 line breaks. maybe it is an apache issue?

Comment: @lolka_bolka No. That's just how browsers work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Browsers ignore the first and last line breaks inside the `<textarea>` tag. This is because if you wouldn't want any extra line breaks if you write the HTML like this:

```
<textarea>
Textarea content, all in one line.
</textarea>
```

The simple solution in this case is to just add one line break before printing the textarea contents.

```
<textarea style="width: 200px; height: 150px;" name="message">
<?php echo $_POST["message"]; ?>
</textarea>
```

Also note that you don't need `\r\n`. Just `\n` is enough.

Answer (score -2):

This should do it

```
<?php echo nl2br($_POST["message"]); ?>
```

Please be aware of XSS attacks on the $_POST variable though.

nl2br php docs: http://php.net/manual/en/function.nl2br.php

xss cheat sheet: https://www.owasp.org/index.php/XSS_(Cross_Site_Scripting)_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet